# No iBook app on iPhone X; cannot find app in App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore, books

I deleted the iBook app from my iPhone X. To get the app back, I assumed I could fetch it from the App Store. But when I searched the store for the app, the only hits I see for apps are for Audible and Amazon.

How can I get the iBook app back and working?

Notes

- I use the app for audiobooks.
- There **is** an audiobook on my phone.
- When I'm plugged into iTunes (on a PC), then through iTunes I can see the tracks and listen to the book.
- The iOS is 11.2.1 and uptodate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open this link on your iOS device, then install the app.

### [<sub><sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub></sub> iBooks by Apple on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8&at=1001lwpF)

When searching for built in apps on the App Store, ‘make sure that you use the exact name of the app’ per the Apple KB article [Remove built-in Apple apps from the Home screen on your iOS 10 device or Apple Watch](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204221). The exact name is ‘iBooks’ so search for this word on the App Store and you should find the app. The first item may be an ad, but the first result below any ad should be the right app.

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it worked for my spousal unit; first he tried "ibooks apple" (no success) and then "ibooks by apple" (success). I am also offering my own answer, which I stumbled on moments ago.

Answer (score 3):

It occurred to me that there might be a connection between ApplePay and my ability to see the apps I wanted at the app store. Some weeks ago I had started but then abandoned installing it.

I completed a few more of the steps, and chose "Do later" for setting up Wallet. Then I went back into the app store. This time I was able to easily find and download the ibooks app.

Note: The answer just before this (from grgarside) worked for my spousal unit who already had Apple Pay fully set up.

Comment: Happy you solved your problem. Since English is not my first language, I am not sure I understand everything. About “spousal”, I find «Law, chiefly North American - relating to marriage or to a husband or wife: ‘the spousal benefits of married couples.’» So, is a “spousal unit” some kind of legal institution?

Comment: "spousal unit" is slang for a husband, wife, or life-partner.